# Adding admob to Android app before or after putting it on android market?

Tags: android

Do i need to put android app to market first before adding admob or some other display ads on the mobile app? As when i was signing up for admob it asks for android url. I am new to this can anyone explain in detail. How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they ask for a URL, they are just looking for a fake, but descriptive URL for your application.  For example, if your application is called "Test1234" and you have www.test1234.com, they suggest you make the URL for your Android application something like:

http://android.test1234.com

Basically it's just a way to distinguish between your applications.